# Connecting custom domain and cloudflare to nginx using debian

Tags: node.js, nginx, debian, webserver, portforwarding

I recently purchased a raspberry pi 4 B+ I plan on using it as a node.js webserver for a project I was working on, I installed nginx and with proxy_pass It now redirects to localhost:5000, here's the problem now, Now I wish to connect it to a custom domain via Cloudflare and for that, I will have to port forward it, but the problem is I can't use the port 80 which is the default port, I need help portforwarding and connecting to domain here are images of my portforwarding:

[image]

[image]

Can someone please tell me what to do?